# Rails HTML sanitizer (Loofah) adds unwanted line breaks between elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sanitization, sanitize

Rails's built-in HTML sanitizer (which uses the gem [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah)) adds newlines between `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. I want to display the sanitized content with `white-space: pre-wrap;` because it comes from a WYSIWYG editor, but the extra newlines make the output look wrong. Desired on top, actual on bottom, with background color added to `ul` for emphasis:

[image: Desired versus actual output of html sanitizing]

Here's what happens when I run some code through the `sanitize` in the rails console:

```
2.2.2 :033 > input = "<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>"
 => "<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>"
2.2.2 :034 > WhiteListSanitizer.new.sanitize(input)
 => "<ul>\n<li>a</li>\n<li>b</li>\n</ul>"
```

And if I make a Loofah object and convert it to html without scrubbing, it still adds newlines.

```
2.2.2 :035 > Loofah.fragment(input).to_html
 => "<ul>\n<li>a</li>\n<li>b</li>\n</ul>"
```

How do I make it leave the whitespace alone?

I can strip out the line breaks with regex if absolutely necessary but it seems strange that there's no option to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude [`FORMAT` option](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/34b2a245578291e251b2d07ed57cb065c443659d/lib/nokogiri/xml/node/save_options.rb#L8) from [`DEFAULT_HTML`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/34b2a245578291e251b2d07ed57cb065c443659d/lib/nokogiri/xml/node/save_options.rb#L33) option (both belong to `Nokogiri`):

```
input = "<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>"
disable_formatting = Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::DEFAULT_HTML ^ Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::FORMAT
Loofah.fragment(input).to_html(save_with: disable_formatting)
# => "<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Loofah is actually using Nokogiri behind the scenes, which defaults to display formatted/indented html -- hence the new line characters. I found [another (similar) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406251/nokogiri-to-xml-without-carriage-returns) regarding this behavior of Nokogiri, and below, is code I believe will work in your case:

```
Loofah.fragment(input).to_html(:save_with => 
Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::AS_XML | 
Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION).strip
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Rails's built-in HTML sanitizer

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize('<script/><ul><li>111</li><li>222</li></ul>', tags: %w(p br ul ol li a), attributes: %w(href))
#=> "<ul>\n" + "<li>111</li>\n" + "<li>222</li>\n" + "</ul>"
```

Loofah can be used directly

```
loofah_fragment = Loofah.fragment('<script/><ul><li>111</li><li>222</li></ul>')
scrubber = Rails::Html::PermitScrubber.new
scrubber.tags = %w(p br ul ol li a)
scrubber.attributes = %w(href)
unformatted_html = Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions.class_eval { |m| m::DEFAULT_HTML ^ m::FORMAT }
loofah_fragment.scrub!(scrubber).to_html(save_with: unformatted_html)
#=> "<ul><li>111</li><li>222</li></ul>"
```